# Compose key doesn't work in some applications [Wayland]

Tags: shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout, chromium, wayland, compose-key

First of: I'm running on Ubuntu 20.04.1 with Gnome (3.36.4) under Wayland (using Mutter 3.36.6).

I'm using the compose key (alt-gr) in order to enter the famous Umlauts (äÄöÖüÜß) on a pure US keyboard. It works without problems in most applications, but I've trouble using it in chromium beta when enabling the ozone platform to have it running with a native wayland renderer. (Compose key works without problems when using chromium with xwayland)

```bsh
# command used for startup
chromium-browser --enable-features=UseOzonePlatform --ozone-platform=wayland
```

I'm pretty sure that this is a problem with chromium (also with chrome, microsoft edge, electron 12, ...), but is there anything I could do for now until this problem is fixed? I've read that `GTK_IM_MODULE=xim` worked in the past, but as far as I know wayland works different here.

Comment: There are new mutter packages in focal-proposed. I have no idea if it would help, but you may want to give an upgrade of the mutter packages a try.

Comment: But is it really an issue with Mutter? Sounds more like an error in the chromium code, because they wrote their own compose key handling routine. The big question is, whether one can switch the handling.

Comment: I don't know. It was a guess. OTOH there are reasons why Ubuntu does not enable Wayland by default.

Comment: You're probably right here

Answer (score 0):

> Fortunately, this issue has already been fixed. The fix will be included in **Chrome 98** (beta release on 2022-01-06, stable release on 2022-02-01), and you can already try it out in the latest Dev build.

Details here: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1142908